# Shopify Predictive Search Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, shopify

I'm quite new to shopify, liquid and all that comes with it. 
I try to implement predective search on shopify and I just don't know why I'm not even getting the alert of the Ajax call that is in the following code. I put it in my "theme.liquid" file right above the closing body tag. I assume if it would work, there should be the alert right when opening the page, no? Goki is a vendor, many products are shown when I search for it on my page. My code looks like this:

```
<script>
jQuery.getJSON("/search/suggest.json", {
  "q": "goki",
  "resources": {
    "type": "product",
    "limit": 4,
    "options": {
      "unavailable_products": "last",
      "fields": "title,product_type,variants.title"
    }
  }
}).done(function(response) {
  var productSuggestions = response.resources.results.products;
  if (productSuggestions.length > 0) {
    var firstProductSuggestion = productSuggestions[0];
    alert("The title of the first product suggestion is: " + firstProductSuggestion.title);
  }
});
</script>
```

Any help would be very very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Make sure the jQuery is loaded before this script is executed. Also, check whether it returns any results as it seems it doesn't. Is your Shopify store available online?

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for your answer! Yes it's available online, menschenskinder-shop.de with vuffey as password. I tried to implement <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> but my slideshow and other things are not working anymore. Also, I have some other jquery implemented (if I see that correctly), so I assume it should work correctly. Can you check if JQuery is loaded on my page? Thank you!!

Comment: If I check with the code following code, I see the alert "Yeah". So I guess JQuery is loaded correctly right?     if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }

Comment: It's weird. It seems to be a problem with the implementation of "search/suggest.json" right after getJSON at the beginning. Or it's about the creation of the term itself, as in the working search url there has to be "?q=" and "&", and maybe it's not created automatically? If I create the url manually it's working, then it looks like this: var q = 'goki'  var url2 = '&resources[type]=product,collection'    and finally    getJSON({
        'url':  "/search/suggest.json?q=" + q + url2, ... Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I created an own variable AjaxData with all the 'resources' parameter before entering the JQuery call. There I don't use the variable to create the url, it's just used to define param in the call, not to change the url. -that's the trick